# Use subscript as index in julia

Tags: unicode, macros, julia

Is it possible to define a macro that replaces all subscript characters by normal characters and encloses them in square brackets? I would like to define the `macro _` as in the example below:

```
F = ones(10)
@_ begin
F₁ = 1
F₂ = 1
map(n-> (Fₙ = Fₙ₋₁ + Fₙ₋₂), 3:10)
end
```

which should evaluate to

```
F = ones(10)
F[1] = 1
F[2] = 1
map(n-> (F[n] = F[n-1] + F[n-2]), 3:10)
```

Comment: It doesn't do what you asked, but.. it could be useful if you manage to get your question working: https://github.com/sylvaticus/MultiDimEquations.jl

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: I don't think it's possible - subscripts aren't valid identifier characters, so Julia lexer will throw an error before a macro has a chance to operate. And even if they were valid identifier chars, this neat syntax won't be possible since F and ₂ together will be seen as a single token and macros can't split individual tokens into pieces like this. (I might be wrong in any detail here though.)